# Doctrine column based on two references

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.2

i have a problem with doctrine.

I want to create the following classes in symfony:

**Device**

- id
- name
- type

**Type**

- id
- name
- attributes

**Attribute**

- id
- name
- value

The problem is that the value from the attribute class based on the device.
So how i have to annotate this?

Edit:
One device has one typ, and one type has multiple attributes.
But a second device with the same type and the same attributes has other values.

Device1 with type thermometer and attribute temperature has the value 15° C.
Device2 with type thermometer and attribute temperature has the value 20° C.

Comment: Can you describe the relations you'll need ? Something like: One device to one type and many types to one device ? What about the relations with attribute class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AttributeType entity

```
Type <-- Device <-- Attribute(value) --> AttributeType
```